# Revolution Slider and data tables not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter, revolution-slider

ok so I can't figure out wtf I did to break this. I once had my revolution slider and my data tables working but now nothing is loading. Let me do my best to run down what I have and let me know if you need anything else to help with this....

I have a library named Functions where I have the following:

```
    public function jsScript($name, $path = 'public/js/')
 {
     return "<script type='text/javascript' src='/min/?f={$path}{$name}{$this->ci->config->item('min_debug')}&amp;  {$this->ci->config->item('min_version')}'></script>" . PHP_EOL;
 }
 /**
  * TODO: short description.
  *
  * @param mixed $cssFile 
  * @param mixed $path    Optional, defaults to 'public/css/'. 
  *
  * @return TODO
  */
 public function cssScript($cssFile, $path = 'public/css/')
 {
     return "<link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href=\"/{$path}{$cssFile}{$this->ci->config->item('min_debug')}{$this->ci->config->item('min_version')}\" />" . PHP_EOL;
 }
```

Controller:

```
  public function index()
     {
     $header['cssheadscript'] = $this->functions->cssScript('revolution/css/settings.css', 'public/plugins/revolution-slider/');

     $header['jsheadscript'] = $this->functions->jsScript('js/jquery.themepunch.tools.min.js', 'public/plugins/revolution-slider/rs-plugin/');
     $header['jsheadscript'] .= $this->functions->jsScript('js/jquery.themepunch.revolution.min.js', 'public/plugins/revolution-slider/rs-plugin/');
     $header['jsheadscript'] .= $this->functions->jsScript('plugins/revolution-slider.js');
     $header['jsheadscript'] .= $this->functions->jsScript('waypoints.min.js', 'public/plugins/counter/');
     $header['jsheadscript'] .= $this->functions->jsScript('jquery.counterup.min.js', 'public/plugins/counter/');
     $header['jsheadscript'] .= $this->functions->jsScript('plugins/pace-loader.js');

     $this->load->view('template/header', $header);
     $this->load->view('welcome/home');
     $this->load->view('template/footer');
 }
```

In my header I load everything required to run the page:

```
    <!-- Web Fonts -->
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600&amp;          subset=cyrillic,latin'>

 <!-- CSS Global Compulsory -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/plugins/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/one.style.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/app.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/blocks.css">


 <!-- CSS Footer -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/footers/footer-v7.css">

 <!-- CSS Implementing Plugins -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/plugins/animate.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/plugins/line-icons/line-icons.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/plugins/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/plugins/pace/pace-flash.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/plugins/cube-portfolio/cubeportfolio/css/cubeportfolio.min.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/plugins/cube-portfolio/cubeportfolio/custom/custom-cubeportfolio.css">

 <!-- Style Switcher -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/plugins/style-switcher.css">

 <!-- CSS Theme -->
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/theme-colors/dark-red.css" id="style_color">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/theme-skins/one.dark.css">

 <!-- CSS Customization -->
 <?php if(!empty($cssheadscript)){echo $cssheadscript;} ?>
 <link rel='stylesheet' href='/public/css/dataTables.min.css'>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/custom.css">

     <!-- JS Global Compulsory -->
 <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>  -->
 <script src="/public/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/public/plugins/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/public/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

 <!-- JS Implementing Plugins -->
 <script src="/public/plugins/smoothScroll.js"></script>
 <script src="/public/plugins/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/public/plugins/pace/pace.min.js"></script>
 <script src="/public/plugins/jquery.parallax.js"></script>
 <script src="/public/plugins/cube-portfolio/cubeportfolio/js/jquery.cubeportfolio.js"></script>
 <!-- JS Page Level-->
 <script src="/public/js/app.js"></script>
 <script src="/public/js/one.app.js"></script>
 <script src="/public/plugins/back-to-top.js"></script>
 <script src="/public/js/plugins/style-switcher.js"></script>
 <script src="/public/js/plugins/cube-portfolio/cube-portfolio-lightbox.js"></script>
 <script src="/public/js/dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <?php if(!empty($jsheadscript)){echo $jsheadscript;}?>
 <script src="/public/js/custom.js"></script>
```

As you can see, I've even tried pulling my jquery from google just to see if that would fix the issue, it doesn't. :/

I have my init's loading after everything else is loaded with:

```
  <script>
      jQuery(document).ready(function() {
          App.init();
          App.initCounter();
          App.initParallaxBg();
          StyleSwitcher.initStyleSwitcher();
          RevolutionSlider.initRSfullScreen();             
      });
  </script>
```

I have tried putting things in different loading orders, tried pulling from new locations. I've checked each file with firebug and all .js files are loading fine. Not sure what the problem is. They were working before and I made changes and now my slider and data tables are broken.

You can see the site live at www.novabl4ck.org. The revolution slider is on the home page, as for the datatables, that's a backend feature so you won't be able to access it.

Any suggestions on what else I can try, something I can do to test, ANY help would be appreciated. javaScript is still fairly new to me and idk if I screwed something up that i'm just unaware of at this point in my learning.

If you need any other info, let me know!

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: you have 2 javascript errors on that page, could you fix those first? i.e. no LoginForm and var reasonlist=document.skyform3.reason is undefined

Comment: Have you set your base url in the config.php as required to do so in latest versions of CI3

Comment: ok, so it trying to load a function on page load that didn't exist on that page is what my issue was. Had to rework some stuff... Thanks for the help!